# Help finding paper: De Concini, Kac - Quantum Groups at roots of 1

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, quantum-groups

I am looking for a specific paper, that I have found very difficult to trace.

*C. De Concini, V. Kac - Quantum Groups at roots of 1*

Specifically, the paper is cited as follows (on De Concini's webpage).

*De Concini, Corrado; Kac, Victor G. Representations of quantum groups at roots of 1.
Operator algebras, unitary representations, enveloping algebras, and invariant theory 
(Paris, 1989), 471--506, Progr. Math., 92, Birkhäuser Boston, Boston, MA, 1990.*

I have seen it cited many times, which seems to suggest that there should be (digital?) copies available. Nevertheless, I have not been able to track the paper down.

It is perhaps important to note that there seems to be another possible source to find the paper.

*De Concini, Corrado; Kac, Victor G. Representations of quantum groups at roots of 1.
Modern quantum field theory (Bombay, 1990), 333--335, World Sci. Publishing, River
Edge, NJ, 1991.*

However, my University does not provide access to World. Sci. Publishing books, and hence the article remains hidden behind a $58 fee.

Any help in obtaining a copy of this paper would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's unfortunately a standard frustration that conference papers in such volumes issued by most publishers are usually expensive (or impossible) to access online, even when the paper versions exist in libraries (such as ours).   It might help to contact one of the authors directly (at U. Rome or MIT), in case they can supply a copy.   In some countries interlibrary loans are also a possibility.  But legal copies are otherwise likely to be scarce.  (Also, the short note in the 1990 conference volume is probably an unhelpfully short summary.)

Comment: P.S. The follow-up paper by De Concini and Kac (along with Procesi) is freely available online: http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1992-05-01/S0894-0347-1992-1124981-X/

Comment: Many thanks for commenting! It really is a shame that these series, such as Progressions in Mathematics are not all being scanned in and made available online. Anyway, I will take up your suggestion on contacting one of the authors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same problem recently and I just found a copy of this paper at this link:http://www.math.harvard.edu/~yfu/Kac-DeConcini.pdf.